# Final Objects of a (Coslice?) Category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm reading Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter 0* and in example 5.6 / exercise 5.5, he asks what the terminal object/objects (he refers to it as singular in the example but in plural in the exercise) are the in following category. He also remarks that its a supremely uninteresting one.

The category is defined as such:

Given an equivalence relation $\sim$ on set $A$,

Objects of the category are morphisms $A \overset{\varphi}{\longrightarrow} Z$  from the set $A$ to any set $Z$ such that $\alpha \sim \alpha' \Rightarrow \varphi(\alpha) = \varphi(\alpha')$ (I think this is an example of a coslice category).

Morphisms between objects $(\varphi_1,Z_1) \rightarrow (\varphi_2,Z_2)$ are defined as morphisms $\sigma$ such that the following commutes (can't draw a commutative diagram with diagonal arrows in mathjax so imagine $A$ being the bottom of a triangle with the other two vertices being $Z_1$ and $Z_2$) :

$$ A \overset{\varphi_1}{\longrightarrow} Ζ_1  \overset{\sigma}{\longrightarrow} Z_2 \overset{\varphi_2}{\longleftarrow} A $$

So far I've figured that both the morphism $(1_A, A)$ (that is the identity morphism from $A$ to $A$) and the morphisms of type $(const_Α, S)$ (where $S$ is any singleton set and $const_A$ is the constant function from $A$ to that set) appear to be final objects in this category.

The unique morphisms from any $(\varphi, Z)$ to $(1_A , A)$ are the reverse functions $\varphi^{-1}$ while the unique morphism for any from any $(\varphi, Z)$ to $(const_Α, S)$ are the corresponding constant functions from $Z$ to the singleton $S$.

Is this correct? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help commenting on this weird mix of intermediate latex (eg, \overset) but not actually putting all math in math mode, also using ASCII characters. It's a good question, I'm just so confused!

Comment: Sorry for that, new here and haven't quite gotten mathjax/latex down. Is it a matter of style or does that detract from the question (that is, are you confused about my poor markdown skills or about the question) ?

Comment: You're fine! I'm probably unusually sensitive to stuff like this, the question itself is perfectly good. Feel free to revert the edit by hitting the "edited [...]" and reverting to your original post (certain things *are* different; the overset letters are smaller now, unfortunately).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, looks much better formatted now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with your answer.

First of all, a terminal object is unique up to (unique) isomorphism. Hence you cannot have two non isomorphic terminal objects.

You are right that the singleton set with the constant map is a terminal object. (And every terminal object is a singleton set).

However, $(id_A,A)$ is not a terminal object. In fact, it is not an object at all unless the equivalence relation $\sim$ is the identity. Remember that an object of your category is a map $\varphi:A\rightarrow Z$ such that $\varphi(a)=\varphi(a')$ if $a\sim a'$. The identity satisfies this condition if and only if $\sim$ is the equality.

But even in that case, it is not the terminal object. You said, the unique function form $(\varphi,Z)$ to $(id_A,A)$ is the reverse function $\varphi^{-1}$. But it does not exist if $\varphi$ is not bijective. Can you show that there is no map from $(const,\{*\})$ to $(id_A,A)$ ?

But for this category, this is the initial object that is very interesting. Can you see what it is ? Hint : it is a usual construction given a set equipped with an equivalence relation.

Comment: So the only terminal objects are the constant/singleton morphisms?
Excellent insight, the initial object was indeed the interesting thing about the whole example (it was actually the very reason Aluffi gave it), and its the projection map if I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes the terminal objects are the singletons. Hence not that interesting, this is the same thing in Sets. The initial object is the quotient $A/\sim$ with the projection map.

Comment: @NullSpace Just to answer OP's last question: the described category is not a coslice category (of $\mathsf{Set}$) per se. However it is equivalent to a coslice category ${}_{S} \backslash \mathsf{Set}$. The set $S$ and the functor realizing the equivalence is very related to the initial object you found, I let you fill in the details.